# Is there any class which have combined functionality of ScaleGestureDetector and GestureDetector?

Tags: android, android-gesture

**Hi to all,**

---

Is there any class which have combined functionality  of ScaleGestureDetector and GestureDetector ?
I am using below code for onTouchEvent but only one gesture class is running. If I want to use all the functions of GestureDetector as well as ScaleGestureDetector

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
    {
        if (mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev))
            return true;
        else if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev))
            return true;
        else
            return false;}
```

where mScaleDetector is ScaleGestureDetector and mGestureDetector is GestureDetector

---

*thanks in advance*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me doing something like

```
return mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent() && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
```

seems to work. The explanation may be that when you do a boolean and between them, it will process both methods in order to obtain the result to be returned.

The issue with your approach may be that you perhaps forgot to return true when one of the gesture methods consumed the event.

Hope this helps,
Mihai

Comment: This code (assuming you meant mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)) should be identical to the OPs code. The && operator does not execute the right hand side if the left hand side returns true, which is exactly what the original code does.

Answer (score 0):

You should always pass `onTouchEvent` parameter to both detectors, otherwise gesture detection may go haywire.

[See example in documentation.](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html)